# How to create html file on the fly in .NET

Tags: .net, dynamic-data, on-the-fly

I am interested to know that how can I create html file on the fly in .NET. I have a scenario in which the user request a page something like

http://mydomain.com/country/123.html

I want to create that html file on the fly, Bind the content of the page dynamically and show it to the end user? Can someone please suggest what should I need to do to make  it possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather odd requirement and without a lot of context it's quite hard to answer.

There are two approaches you could take.

The first would be to analyse the request as it comes in in the Global.cs's `Application_BeginRequest` method. If it didn't request you could then create the file in question.

Your other option would be to create a [HttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227675%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and direct traffic to it. This wouldn't actually create the file on the server but depending on your requirements it could meet your requirements.